# Вывод ошибки javascript в Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

Помогите решить проблему с выводом ошибки javascript в gulp при помощи плагинов, которые выводят ошибку в отдельном окне, как notyfication. Для less настроил, а вот для **javascript** не выходит подтянуть этот функционал. Gulp начал пользоваться совсем недавно, поэтому прошу помощи.

**Все подключенные плагины**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    rigger = require('gulp-rigger'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    multipipe = require('multipipe'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    errorNotifier = require('gulp-error-notifier'),
    rimraf = require('rimraf'),
    browserSync = require("browser-sync"),
    reload = browserSync.reload;
```

**Таск для для обработки js файлов, тут если можно помогите настроить, чтобы можно было выводить ошибку.**

```
gulp.task('js:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.js)
        .pipe(rigger())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});
```

Вот небольшое [**видео**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otkXzef2wQY) по которому настроил для less, попробовал тот же подход для js не вышло, возможно что-то не так делаю.

Answer (score 1):

Установите модуль `gulp-util`.

А в вызове сделайте так -

```
gulp.task('js:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.js)
        .pipe(rigger())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(uglify().on('error', gutil.log))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});
```

И не забудьте в импорт модулей добавить `var gutil = require('gulp-util');`

Соответствено логгируйте там - где ошибка.

Comment: Это хорошо, только чуть выше вызывается сборщик, который собирает все подключенный плагины. У меня они подключены в основном фале js, локализовать такую ошибку будет трудно.

Comment: И получается придется каждый раз лезть в консоль, чтобы локализовать ошибку?

Comment: Вот пример кода, где подключаются плагины. Получается, если будет ошибка, то строка кода будет на 9999... такой подход будет сложно локализовать.